# -webkit-tap-highlight-color tap issue on in mobile, will text appear hidden

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am using below code but when tap on greybox section text/image appear hidden. I am trying other ways but issue not resolved. Can any one help me please which will appreciate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height,  initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;user-scalable=0;"/>
<style>
    *{-webkit-tap-highlight-color:#eaeaea; -tap-highlight-color:#eaeaea; -moz-tap-highlight-color:#eaeaea; -webkit-appearance:none;}
    .brands ul{ margin:0; padding:0; float:left; width:100%;}
    .brands ul li{ width:50%; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:1px; float:left; box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; }

    .brands ul li div{ float:left; width:100%; position:relative;}
    .brands ul li div a{background:#f6f6f6; min-height:60px; text-align:center; display:block; height: 70px; overflow: hidden;   float:left; width:100%; position:relative; cursor:pointer; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="brands">
    <ul>
        <li><div><a>Test</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a>Test</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a>Test</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a>Test</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a>Test</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a>Test</a></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. I am using rgba color code instead short color code

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    -tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    -moz-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    -webkit-appearance:none;
  }
```